# Can I set a custom NPM repository to be used by JSS?

Tags: jss

Is there a way I can set a custom NPM repository to be used by JSS when running a `jss deploy`? I have a package dependency which is hosted in a dev repository (for the moment) and this is breaking my `jss deploy`...

```
cross-env-shell PUBLIC_URL=$npm_package_config_sitecoreDistPath "react-scripts build"

Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`
Failed to compile.
Cannot find module: '@hsantos/hsantos-module'. Make sure this package is installed.
You can install this package by running: npm install @hsantos/hsantos-module.
```

However, when I run `npm config set @hsantos:registry https://npm.dev.cloud.hsantos.com` + `npm install @hsantos/hsantos-module` the module is installed properly...

That leads me to think that during the `jss deploy` somehow the `npm install` is called but my custom NPM repository `https://npm.dev.cloud.hsantos.com` is not being taken into account.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `jss deploy app` nor `jss deploy files` run `npm install`.

`jss deploy app` is an alias for `jss deploy items` and `jss deploy files`.

`jss deploy files` will, by default, run `jss build` before copying files to a local Sitecore instance.

`jss build` will, in turn, effectively run `npm run build:client`, which runs `react-scripts build` and is seemingly where your error is being generated.

You may want to try troubleshooting by directly running `npm run build:client` and working your way from there. The `cannot find module` error message you're receiving is originating from webpack when it is trying to build your app bundle.